Support needed for quartz tabletop?
Im planning to buy bar height steel table legs or a frame to support a ~30”x52” slab of 3cm quartz. I’m unsure of the amount of support that will be required for this.
Would I be okay with two “H” shaped legs on either end that aren’t connected, or would i absolutely need one or two support beams supporting the underside of the slab lengthwise? Maybe a 3rd leg in the center with a 3/4 plywood panel between the legs and the slab?
Update
I’m planning to go with three “U” shaped legs made of 2”x2” steel, each with a 4” mounting plate on the top. I’d attach a 3/4” plywood sheet to those plates then the quartz slab would be mounted to the plywood. I’m also planning to secure the steel legs to the concrete subfloor to lock it in as it will be very top heavy with the legs being 18” wide and 38” tall.
Please let me know if you need any additional information or if I should rethink the whole thing entirely.

Depends a lot on details you haven't provided. How wide are the attachment points of the legs? The major concern would be racking (someone bumps the table, it rocks to the side) that could pull screws out of the top. If the legs/attachments are pretty wide, they bay be wide enough to prevent this on their own. If not, you'll want some sort of diagonal stiffener to prevent this. A drawing of the design & spec sheet of the intended legs would help.

I suspect you will want a metal frame of some sort supporting the actual slab.  A slab is heavy and has very little flexural strength of its own.
